# Using Index and Match functions to return a value from multiple worksheets in a workbook

Tags: regex, excel, indexing, match, vlookup

I have a url report that gets generated on a running weekly basis. Each week the report generates a new worksheet within a workbook that keeps around 6 months worth of data at a time. I want to find and pull the data on a specific url from the worksheets and display them in a new worksheet.

For example data in a worksheet might look like:

> Week of Mar 9
>   URL | Visits | Conversions 
>   mysite.com/apple | 300 | 10
>   mysite.com/banana | 100 | 20 
>   mysite.com/pear | 600 | 5

And each worksheet in the workbook is a different week, such as Mar 2, Feb 23, etc.

Now, I want every Apple url in one worksheet so that I can compare...Apples to Apples...(pun intended). Since there are hundreds of these I can't afford the time to manually do this for each segment I need, so I tried the following.

=INDEX('312015'!8:999,MATCH("apple",'312015'!8:999,-1))

I'm uncertain of which switch to use for Match, other than 0 is "exact match" from what I read online, so I tried both 1 and -1 to get a not-exact match, though reality is I probably need a partial-match since apple is only part of the url.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work or a better way to do this in excel would be great. Also, I can not manipulate the report output themselves as it comes from a third party vendor and I've already asked them about adjusting this.

I thought about using vlookup as well, but I believe that only returns the first result with that value and not multiple ones.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `URL` in ColumnA, `Visits` in ColumnB, `Conversions` in ColumnC for your source data, and in another sheet your page (fruit: apple/banana/pear) in A1,`Visits` in B1, `Conversions` in C1 and sheet names in A2 downwards, then I suggest in B2:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT($A2&"!B:B"),MATCH("*"&$A$1,INDIRECT($A2&"!A:A"),0))
```

in C2:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT($A2&"!C:C"),MATCH("*"&$A$1,INDIRECT($A2&"!A:A"),0))
```

and the two formulae copied down to suit.

This is looking for an exact match but does so with a wildcard.